# xcode 6 beta 3: keyboard doesn't show up when selecting textField

Tags: xcode6

Has anyone encountered this situation?

When I was trying to run application, which was completed in Xcode6Beta, it kept showing:

> 2014-07-14 00:28:48.131 WeightLogger2[1866:32214] Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using 2617181025_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You just need to toggle the software keyboard by selecting:

iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard.

Then, everything works

Comment: the keyboard shows up but the warning on terminal is still there... should I be concerned?

Answer (score 3):

uncheck this option

```
iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard
```

however if you are using number pad or decimal pad then this log again will be displayed, but in simulator you can use the number pad or decimal pad. may be we need to configure our text field with the new preferred way of using keyboard with ios 8. I could not found it yet. or it may be a bug according to this

[Xcode iOS 8 Keyboard types not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871532/xcode-ios-8-keyboard-types-not-supported)

Comment: Turning off the hardware keyboard will mean that you'll need to input all text with the software keyboard via mouse clicks.  In Xcode 6.0, we moved to a model where the host's keyboard acts as closely as possible to a bluetooth keyboard connected to a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, apple may rejected your app due to this. They complained that the app did no allow the user to enter input on an iPad. So you can respond that the app works fine on an actual iPad and that on a simulator all one has to due is disable external keyboard or toggle SW keyboard. They will accept this comment and allowed the app to be approved.