# Xcode iOS 8 Keyboard types not supported

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, swift, ios8

I have a `UITextField` Ctrl-dragged as an `@Outlet` in my `.swift` class.
Now in `viewDidLoad` i'm using this code

```
self.myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad
```

When i launch my app on simulator and click on the `UITextField` i got this log

```
    Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard 
    iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; 
    using 2617181025_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
```

I have no crash or something but the keyboard is not displayed. I also tried to set it from `Storyboard` but it's the same.

I also noticed that whenever i click on *any* `UITextField` the keyboard is never displayed (but no log is shown for the **default** keyboard)

I'm using Xcode-Beta 3 anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25954053/3497544)

Comment: Still a problem only on simulator thou. Xcode 8.3

Comment: None of the answers in this page is relevant anymore (as of July 2017), at least with Xcode 8.

Comment: Xcode 11.2.1.  Physical iPhone X.  Same problem.

Comment: @VinceO'Sullivan How was this solved??

Comment: @H.Jacob I retired!  Happily, I no longer have to worry about this kind of stuff anymore.  

Answer (score 213, accepted):

I too had this problem after updating to the latest Xcode Beta. The settings on the simulator are refreshed, so the laptop (external) keyboard was being detected. If you simply press:

```
 iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard
```

then the software keyboard will be displayed once again.

Comment: Yes I posted the same method in a comment of another post, in this way the keyboard is shown but the warning log still stays.

Comment: If you uncheck this, though, it appears that you can no longer type using your Mac's keyboard?

Comment: selecting iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard enabled Mac's Keyboard

Comment: I'm seeing it on a physical device (iPhone 5) running the Xcode 6 & iOS GM.

Comment: I am also getting this on an iPhone 6 with the latest Xcode from the App Store.

Comment: As someone said in another thread, you can now use cmd+K to switch between the simulator and mac keyboards.

Comment: The keyboard shows but the warning is still there even with the official version of xcode

Comment: Still exist in Xcode 6.1. I am running in iPhone 5 device

Comment: For me, in 6.1 I have Connect Hardware Keyboard unchecked, and the decimal pad displays fine, but I get this error message every time a text field becomes first responder.

Comment: any fix for this?? getting it on phone5s running Xcode 6.4

Comment: Xcode 7.1 - the same , it doesn't look like they are going to do anything about it.

Comment: Xcode 7.1.1 the same, do we add a comment every version? :D

Comment: Still same problem :D

Comment: XCode 7.3 iPhone 6 iOS 9.3, still there

Comment: XCode 8.0 iPhone 4s iOS 8.4.1 and it's still there.

Comment: what about physical device???? it's not simulator and all answer are for simulator

Comment: The key board is visible, but I am unable to type using my mac keyboard.. have to use the mouse.. just to crazy

Comment: Xcode 10.2.1 with iOS 12 (emulator) and the message is logged when I click on a "Decimal Pad" InputField (doesn't happen with a "Default" one). Checking "Connect Hardware Keyboard" simply disabled my hardware keyboard for InputFields (had to click it again to bring it back) but it didn't get rid of the message.

Comment: @Tony Abboud Bro, I did not navigate to `iOS Simulator`. How can I go to that path??

Answer (score 34):

Go to `iOS Simulator-> Hardware-> Keyboard ->` Uncheck the `Connect Hardware Keyboard` Option.
This will fix the issue.

Comment: Happens even when this is unchecked.

Answer (score 20):

This message comes when the keyboard type is set to numberPad or DecimalPad. But the code works just fine. Looks like its a bug with the new Xcode.

Comment: Still true to this day. "Looks like its a bug with the new Xcode."

Answer (score 18):

If you're getting this bug with Xcode Beta, it's a beta bug and can be ignored (as far as I've been told). If you can build and run on a release build of Xcode without this error, then it is not your app that has the problem.

Not 100% on this, but see if this fixes the problem:

iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard.

Then, everything works

Comment: Hey your solutions is not working, **BUT** i tried to uncheck the `iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard` , now the keyboard is shown even thought i am not able to type from my mac keyboard and the warning is still present in the logs

Comment: Sorry I've taken so long to reply, I've been trying to debug my own app.

Whats happening is your textfields are telling your keyboard the text is a negative size. You need to either change the text size to a .xxx or resize your textfield bigger.

Comment: But I simply crtl-dragged the `UITextField` from the panel to my storyboard, nothing else. Is it a bug of `Xcode-Beta 3`?

Comment: Try replacing the text box with a new one. I had this same problem which is how I found yours. It was caused by my text box being smaller then default. It IS possible though. Check the developer forums!

Comment: I have same issue.. it works if you set the Keyboard Type to default. Not the decimal or Number pad..  very strange

Comment: It seams this is mostly a beta bug, as if you run this on a non beta version it doesn't have the issue. It can easily be ignored as long as it does not affect usability.

Answer (score 15):

I have fixed this issue by unchecking 'Connect Hardware Keyboard'. Please refer to the image below to fix this issue[image]

Answer (score 4):

Xcode: 6.4 iOS:8
I got this error as well, but for a very different reason.

```
//UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad needs a "Done" button    
UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                              target:self
                                                                              action:@selector(doneBarButtonTapped:)];

enhancedNumpadToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]init]; // previously declared
[self.enhancedNumpadToolbar setItems:@[doneBarButton]];
self.myNumberTextField.inputAccessoryView = self.enhancedNumpadToolbar; //txf previously declared
```

I got the same error (save mine was "type 4" rather than "type 8"), until I discovered that I was missing this line:

```
[self.enhancedNumpadToolbar sizeToFit];
```

I added it, and the sun started shining, the birds resumed chirping, and all was well with the world.

PS You would also get such an error for other mischief, such as forgetting to alloc/init.

Comment: I'm having this problem, and even with sizeToFit I get the same warning.

Comment: I'd need to see your code to see if I have any insight, since this error can be caused by any number of things going wrong. [Sorta like entropy, or Tolstoy's _bon mot_ about dysfunctional home life:
“All happy families are alike; each unhappy family is unhappy in its own way.”] Can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

This error had come when your keyboard input type is Number Pad.I got same error than I change my Textfield keyboard input type to Default fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Numeric Keypad" for iPads out of the box.  When you specify one iPads display the normal keypad with the numeric part displayed.  You can switch over to alpha characters, etc.  If you want to display a numbers only keyboard for iPad you must implement it yourself.

See here:  [Number keyboard in iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409483/number-keyboard-in-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

iOS Simulator -> I/O -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard

I was facing similar issues but above flow chart is the fix for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just press ⌘ K to toggle the keypad on simulator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

For me turning on and off the setting on

iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard

proved to fix the issue on simulators.