# Receiving notifications from custom 'Done' button on numeric keyboard not working in iOS 8.3

Tags: keyboard, ios8.3

I've added a custom 'Done' button to the numeric keypad using a solution posted in other threads, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842168/cant-find-keyplane-that-supports-type-4-for-keyboard-iphone-portrait-numberpad).  Something has changed with the update to iOS 8.3, as the button still appears but touch notifications never fire off.  Moving the button from the keyboard view to the superview ruins the location of the button, but proves the notifications for the control work.

It behaves like the custom button is behind a transparent layer on the keyboard and no touches are able to take place.

```
- (void)addButtonToKeyboard
{
// create custom button
self.doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163+44, 106, 53);
self.doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
[self.doneButton setTag:67123];
[self.doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doneup1.png"]        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"donedown1.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[self.doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// locate keyboard view
int windowCount = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count];
if (windowCount < 2) {
    return;
}

UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
UIView* keyboard;

for(int i = 0 ; i < [tempWindow.subviews count] ; i++)
{
    keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    // keyboard found, add the button

    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES){
        UIButton* searchbtn = (UIButton*)[keyboard viewWithTag:67123];
        if (searchbtn == nil)//to avoid adding again and again as per my requirement (previous and next button on keyboard)
            [keyboard addSubview:self.doneButton];

    }//This code will work on iOS 8.0
    else if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetContainerView"] == YES){

        for(int i = 0 ; i < [keyboard.subviews count] ; i++)
        {
            UIView* hostkeyboard = [keyboard.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

            if([[hostkeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetHost"] == YES){
                UIButton* donebtn = (UIButton*)[hostkeyboard viewWithTag:67123];
                if (donebtn == nil)//to avoid adding again and again as per my requirement (previous and next button on keyboard)
                    [hostkeyboard addSubview:self.doneButton];
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, I solved this issue by adding button directly on UITextEffectsWindow. Also I've changed the button frame.

```
- (void)addButtonToKeyboar {
// create custom button
self.doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 53, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 3, 53);
self.doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
[self.doneButton setTag:67123];
[self.doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doneup1.png"]        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"donedown1.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[self.doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// locate keyboard view
int windowCount = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count];
if (windowCount < 2) {
    return;
}

UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
UIButton* donebtn = (UIButton*)[tempWindow viewWithTag:67123];
if (donebtn == nil)//to avoid adding again and again as per my requirement (previous and next button on keyboard)
    [tempWindow addSubview:self.doneButton]; }
```

Comment: does this solution work for all cases. all iPhones and all iOS versions?

Comment: sure, my project supports iOS 7+

Answer (score 0):

*objectAtIndex:1* may not target window index every time. So code should check by its description whether window is UITextEffectsWindow or not as below.

```
if (windowCount < 2) {
    return;

} else {
    periodButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 53, 106, 53);
    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if ([[window description] hasPrefix:@"<UITextEffectsWindow"]) {
            [window addSubview:periodButton];
        }
    }

}
```