# Several errors when running my first iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm able to run the app initially (no visible errors), but when I input a number in the ageBox area and press the getAge button, I get several errors.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var ageBox: UITextField!


    @IBAction func getAge(sender: AnyObject) {

        println(ageBox.text)
    }


    @IBOutlet var answerLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Here is the error I get:

> 2015-04-21 10:36:24.183 Cat Years[5284:2484424] Can't find keyplane
>   that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad;
>   using 2705787216_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
>
> 2015-04-21 10:36:25.826 Cat Years[5284:2484424] Can't find keyplane
>   that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad;
>   using 2705787216_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
>
> 5
>
> 2015-04-21 10:36:27.067 Cat Years[5284:2484424]
>   -[Cat_Years.ViewController getAgeButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc881e287f0
>
> 2015-04-21 10:36:27.078 Cat Years[5284:2484424] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[Cat_Years.ViewController getAgeButton:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x7fc881e287f0'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>
> (
>
> 0 CoreFoundation 0x00000001044c5c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
>
> 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000106030bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
>
> 2 CoreFoundation 0x00000001044cd0ad -[NSObject(NSObject)
>   doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
>
> 3 CoreFoundation 0x000000010442313c ***forwarding*** + 988
>
> 4 CoreFoundation 0x0000000104422cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
>
> 5 UIKit 0x0000000104d65da2 -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
>
> 6 UIKit 0x0000000104e7754a -[UIControl
>   _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
>
> 7 UIKit 0x0000000104e76919 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
>
> 8 UIKit 0x0000000104db2998 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
>
> 9 UIKit 0x0000000104db32c2 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 682
>
> 10 UIKit 0x0000000104d79581 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
>
> 11 UIKit 0x0000000104d86d1c _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent +
>   18265
>
> 12 UIKit 0x0000000104d615dc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
>
> 13 CoreFoundation 0x00000001043f9431
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>
> 14 CoreFoundation 0x00000001043ef2fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
>
> 15 CoreFoundation 0x00000001043ee934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
>
> 16 CoreFoundation 0x00000001043ee366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
>
> 17 GraphicsServices 0x00000001084aca3e GSEventRunModal + 161
>
> 18 UIKit 0x0000000104d64900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
>
> 19 Cat Years 0x00000001042c8007 main + 135
>
> 20 libdyld.dylib 0x0000000106788145 start + 1
>
> )
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

Any ideas?

Comment: If you get the error `SIGABRT` if probably means your connections aren't correct. (From the storyboard to code). Just look up any question on fixing this and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Copied your code to a new project. Added a text box, switch, and label. Did the connections. Added constraints using "Add Missing Constraints". And it all worked (with no modification to your view controller code). Here is the link:

[Project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s5vws1xx2t1cf1a/AADwpHxLXf3K_jf03KG-8KYRa?dl=0)

The possibilities I can think of (based on errors I made when I started): (1) in changing connections while editing the storyboard I found that deleted controls are not automatically deleted in the xml file. Suggest you look in the connections editor to see if there are controls that you deleted. (2) do a "clean" to make sure.

Good luck

Comment: Very valuable input.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the keyplane error,try this:

For reference:see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842168/cant-find-keyplane-that-supports-type-4-for-keyboard-iphone-portrait-numberpad)

```
   iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard
```

so that the entry is UNchecked then the software keyboard will be displayed once again.

For the NSInvalidArgumentException',try this:

```
    @IBAction func getAge(sender: UIButton) {
println(ageBox.text)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but no dice.

Comment: The same errors (I would have pasted it, but it's too long and stackoverflow won't allow it).