# ios swift when setting text field to number pad cause strange bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, debugging

I have a text field set to **Keyboard Type > Number Pad**

When I touch the input my console outputs this error:

**Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 1730230351_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default**

After googling it I first thought it had something to do with the simulator eg "toggle software keyboard" etc.

But I have tested this on two of my own phones, a 5s and 6 plus. I still get the error, so its not just a bug in the simulator.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: did you try to reset the simulator

Comment: @Lamar yes, its not just happening in the simulator. I get it on my own phones as well. Tried a 5s / 6 plus

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842168/cant-find-keyplane-that-supports-type-4-for-keyboard-iphone-portrait-numberpad

Comment: @Lamar Thanks, but there is no solution in that thread

Comment: they said to uncheck something for the keyboard to work ... read the last solution

Comment: @Lamar I've tried it as well. But I dont care for the simulator. I get the error on real devices

Comment: Did you update your Xcode or the device? if you did it might a bug.... try to delete the app on your device restart your computer and device then try it again

Comment: @Lamar I just tried it, still get the warning : /

Comment: did you set the textfield delegate

Comment: Does it actually crash? Or just display the error in the console?

Comment: @remus it never crashes. It just outputs an error/warning in the console. Both the simulator and when testing on a real device.

Comment: Hrm in that case I'd leave it - possibly an expected notification.

Comment: @remus Well since it doesnt cause any more problems so yeah. Nothing else sticks out, memory-wise etc. But do you think Apple will deny my app because of this?

Comment: Not likely - they probably won't even notice.

Comment: Did you try To uncheck the hardware keyboard?

iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to simulator-Hardware-Keyboard and uncheck the Connect Hardware Keyboard Option.
This will fix this bug