# On device: Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 563160167_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

Tags: ios, keyboard

I'm seeing this warning while running on my device:

> Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard
>   iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using
>   563160167_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

I've seen a lot of posts about this happening on the simulator:
[Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 3876877096_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842168/cant-find-keyplane-that-supports-type-4-for-keyboard-iphone-portrait-numberpad)

But this is happening for me on a real device.

Comment: I got exactly the same issue. Tested with a new Single View Application, same issue.

Comment: Did you got any solution for this problem??