# Swift - Soft keyboard won't appear OR Hardware keyboard won't work

Tags: swift, ios-simulator

I am trying to make the soft keyboard appear on my iOS simulator. For some reason it just won't show.

I keep getting this error as I select the `TextField`

> Can't find keyplane that supports type 5 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitTruffle-PhonePad; using

I have tried to enabling / disable `Hardware->Keyboard->Connect Hardware Keyboard` as some SO answers recommended.

**EDIT**

Previously, the `Connect Hardware Keyboard` was enabled, I was able to type on my mac keyboard, also the soft keyboard poped up. For some reason after I `disable` the `Connect Hardware Keyboard` option, I cannot type on my mac keyboard anymore.

Comment: Sometimes simply restarting the simulator fixes this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Simulator-> Hardware->Keyboard and uncheck Connect Hardware Keyboard. It will work

This problem seems to be there in many devices https://bugreport.apple.com/logon Post a bug.. Hope apple will fix this bug

Comment: The keyboard now shows but I cannot use my mac keyboard to type anything. Why is that..

Comment: let me know what happens in your system. give your app link

Answer (score 2):

Make sure iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard is not checked if you aren't using a hardware keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842168/cant-find-keyplane-that-supports-type-4-for-keyboard-iphone-portrait-numberpad/25954053#25954053).

Though most of the answers trying to fix it with Connect Hardware Keyboard, one of them is referring to sizing the [views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32016397/5479510).

Another good point was mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33850829/5479510):

> The emulator tries to find a numeric keypad on the mac, but this is not found (MacBook Pro, MacBook Air and "normal/small" keyboard do not have it). You can deselect the option Connect Hardware Keyboard or just ignore the error message, it will have no negative effect on application.

And one more [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997274/5479510):

```
iOS Simulator-> Hardware-> Keyboard -> iOS uses same layout as OS X
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this appears only to be a problem in the latest version of Xcode (and tools). The quickest and most robust solution I've found is to simply **restart the Simulator**.

I expect this is a bug and will be fixed in a later release.