# Fix warning: Failed to set (lineColor) user defined inspected property on (Project.UnderlinedTextField)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uistoryboard

I keep getting this warning:

```
2020-08-22 17:33:31.484454-0500 bob-app-ios[95799:7064579] 
Failed to set (lineColor) user defined inspected property on 
(projectName.UnderlinedTextField): [<projectName.UnderlinedTextField 0x7fbca5084e00> 
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key lineColor.
```

When running my project in a simulator, this is my `UnderlinedTextField` class:

```
import UIKit

class UnderlinedTextField: UITextField {
    var isWriting = false
    let bottomLine = CALayer()
    
    func underlined() {
        self.delegate = self
        
        let width = CGFloat(1.0)
        reloadUnderlinedTextField()
        bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        bottomLine.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
    
    func reloadUnderlinedTextField() {
        bottomLine.borderColor = isWriting ? ColorManager.PrimaryColor?.cgColor : ColorManager.Gray500?.cgColor
    }
}

extension UnderlinedTextField: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let maxLength = 1
        let currentString: NSString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
        let newString: NSString =
            currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
        return newString.length <= maxLength
    }
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        isWriting = true
        reloadUnderlinedTextField()
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        isWriting = false
        reloadUnderlinedTextField()
    }
}
```

Should I worry about it? How could I fix it?

I also get this warning:

```
2020-08-22 17:33:32.683970-0500 projectName[95799:7064579] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 
for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 25752_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
```

My app is not crashing but I feel like those warnings should be taken care of, so, any help might be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are expecting **lineColor** on **UnderlinedTextField** then you need to add following code

```
@IBInspectable var lineColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

You also need to add **@IBDesignable** designation above your class, when applied to a UIView or NSView subclass, as it lets Interface Builder know that it should render the view directly in the canvas. This allows seeing how your custom views will appear without building and running your app after each change.
[More details can be found here](https://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/#:%7E:text=When%20applied%20to%20a%20UIView,your%20app%20after%20each%20change.)

If you don't need **lineColor** on **UnderlinedTextField** then:

1. Search (**⌘ + ⇧ + F**) for **lineColor** in **xib(s)** and **Storyboard(s)**
2. Find where you have assigned class **UnderlinedTextField** to
   **UITextfield(s)**
   Go to Identity Inspector
3. Remove lineColor under **User Defined Runtime Attributes**
4. Build and Run

[image]

As for the second warning please [visit here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25954053/3030400)

Answer (score 0):

As i know, You can't silence this warning

```
2020-08-22 17:33:32.683970-0500 projectName[95799:7064579] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 
for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 25752_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
```

About lineColor, You need to select your UnderlinedTextField in Storyboard and remove lineColor property from this ->
[image]

I'm practically sure that You will find it there