# Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard

Tags: keyboard, swift5, xcode12, iphone11

I get this message in logs when the keyboard opens and after that not able to tap on any element on the screen. Neither textfield nor buttons are tappable. I'm using a simulator iPhone XS Max.

> Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard
> iPhone-PortraitTruffle-NumberPad; using
> 25901_PortraitTruffle_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

Comment: did you get the answer? i faces the same problem in my imulator

Answer (score 3):

I received this error when using the `.keyboardType(.numberPad)` modifier on a `Textfield`.  When I substitute `.numbersAndPunctuation` for the fields keyboard type, this error does not appear anymore.  While numbersAndPunctuation is a similar type to numberPad it may not be as limiting to the user as you intend.  Consider that this is a non-crashing error.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make silent the warning, toggle keyboard as described here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842168/cant-find-keyplane-that-supports-type-4-for-keyboard-iphone-portrait-numberpad][1]

Quote:

If you simply press:

iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard

So that the entry is UNchecked, then the software keyboard will be displayed once again.