# in iOS 8 when clicking on uitextfield keyboard is not open

Tags: objective-c

I add one uitextfield in storyboard . when clicking on uitextfield keyboard is not showing
errors is:Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 2382260317_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode iOS 8 Keyboard types not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871532/xcode-ios-8-keyboard-types-not-supported)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your iOS simulator, make sure that you've unchecked Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard.