# Number keyboard in iPad?

Tags: ipad, numeric-keypad

Is it possible to display keyboard consisting of only numbers from 0-9 in iPad?, i don't want the keyboard to display anything else. I know there is this **KeyboardType:Number Pad** that we can in the .xib file, but it displays all other extra characters including numbers. I want to use this concept in displaying keyboard for PIN login for my iPad application that I'm working on. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to implement your own keyboard if you want this on iPad.

There are many examples out there:

https://github.com/azu/NumericKeypad

https://github.com/lnafziger/Numberpad

https://github.com/benzado/HSNumericField

Comment: Thanks @bjtitus, so there is no inbuilt fix for this, right? that'l do. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sashi Unfortunately, no, there is not a built in number-only (phone/pin) keyboard on iPad.

Comment: Here's another version that worked very well for me, and is available as a CocoaPod:

https://github.com/marcjordant/NumericKeyboard

Answer (score -2):

You may be looking for: `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` which will display numbers and a decimal point.

This is a useful resource: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIKeyboardType

Comment: This does not show the same keypad as the iPhone pin keypad. It shows a number keyboard with special characters included as well.