# Numeric keyboard for ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, keyboard

I am using the numeric keyboard for ipad and iPhone. The problem is it displays correctly on iphone but on ipad it has the option to type the non numeric characters as well.
I have already validated the input and filtering it so that only the numeric data get typed in but i want to remove that alphabet part totally from the keyboard view. I have read many articles suggesting that i would need to implement the custom keyboard. Is there any other way than the custom keyboard that i can do it quickly. My coding platform is swift.
Any help would be appreciate able.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number keyboard in iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409483/number-keyboard-in-ipad)