# NumberPad for iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

I set Number Pad for my TextField on the Storyboard, because I need only numbers for my app. But it works for iPhone only. I can't find solution for iPad. I tried

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.myTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
```

but it doesn't work. Help me please.

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409483/number-keyboard-in-ipad

Comment: @RobertDresler I did read it. But all of it for Objective-C

Comment: The answer still stands, since the underlying SDK/system is the same. If you want number pad on iPad you need a custom keyboard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

iPad doesn't have number only keyboard. You should implement your own. There are some git projects you can use like these:

### - Some Swift Repositories:

- [NumericKeyboard](https://github.com/marcjordant/NumericKeyboard)
- [NumPad](https://github.com/efremidze/NumPad)
- [NumberPad](https://github.com/OlegKetrar/NumberPad)
- [KBNumberPad](https://github.com/kbiakov/KBNumberPad)

### - Some Objective-c Repositories:

- [HSNumericField](https://github.com/benzado/HSNumericField)
- [NumericKeypad](https://github.com/azu/NumericKeypad)
- [NumberPad](https://github.com/lnafziger/Numberpad)

Comment: Thank you. But all of it for Objective-C

Comment: Updated @SheronLi

Comment: @SheronLi you can use objective c lib in swift also, if they dont have, make it acessible in swift urself by making bridging header.