# Only show numeric keyboard just like iPhone on iPad is possible?

Tags: react-native

I have try all of type with `keyboardType`, it will shows number and others characters on `iPad`.

[image]

What I try the keyboardType includes `'default', 'email-address', 'numeric', 'phone-pad', 'ascii-capable', 'numbers-and-punctuation', 'url', 'number-pad', 'name-phone-pad', 'decimal-pad', 'twitter', 'web-search'`

```
<TextInput 
  style={styles.textInput}
  keyboardType='numeric'
  onChangeText={(tex) => this.changeText(tex)}
  value={this.state.text}
  placeholder={'0912 345 678'}
  placeholderTextColor='rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.41)'
/>
```

Is any way to achieve it just shows numeric keyboard ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that iPads do not contain a number only keyboard..
In order to achieve one, you will need to create your own numeric keypad.

There are some good examples suggested by @bjtitus [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27409533/11129555).

Hope you will also find this [Github Link](https://github.com/ZombieWonderland/Numbers-Keyboard) helpful.