# Can't find keyplane that supports type for keyboard

Tags: ios, ios8, keyboard, uitextfield, uikit

I have UITextField for entering e-mails. All is work - but I have this issue in debugger terminal:

```
Can't find keyplane that supports type 7 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-Emoji-Email; 
using 1582125428_Portrait_iPhone-Emoji-Keyboard_Letters
```

[image]

How can I fixed it?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24900682/1310204) may help?

Comment: Thanks @NikolayMamaev but no, because I'm seeing it on a physical device (iPhone 5) with latest iOS running the latest Xcode.

Comment: @WINSergey Did you find the solution for this one? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @gaurang sure and of course not remember, advice is look to another question coz i'm didn't remember ATM