# Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard error UITextfield focus

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I use `UITextfield` in custom cell . when I focus in my `Textfield` get this warning error :

```
 Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 3876877096_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
```

what is this error???

Comment: The same issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871532/xcode-ios-8-keyboard-types-not-supported

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the NumberPad Keyboard Setting.

Go to iOS Simulator-> Hardware-> Keyboard -> Uncheck the Connect Hardware Keyboard Option. This will fix the issue.

Comment: No I get something similar "Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-LandscapeChoco-NumberPad; using 76885345_LandscapeChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default" without having Hardware Keyboard connected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an Beta bug. I have a simmular problem with my Swift app. Xcode 6.2 Beta. Do you use the Beta as well?