# Why am I not getting the keyboard SwiftUI TextField

Tags: swiftui

I have a 3 TextFields in SwiftUI. one on top and two side by side underneath that.

```
VStack{
    //TF1
    TextField("Duty", text: $dutyNumber)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .padding([.leading], 50)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
    HStack{
        //TF2
        TextField("Start time", text: $dutyStartTime)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .padding([.leading], 50)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
        //TF3 
        TextField("Finish time", text: $dutyFinishTime)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .padding([.leading], 50)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
    }
}.cornerRadius(4)
```

However only the last textfield TF3 is interactive. Cannot select the first two TF1 & TF2. Can Tab into them with keyboard but cannot select them with a finger tap. If I change the order from TF1, TF2, TF3 to TF1, TF3, TF2 for example. Then TF2 is now interactive but TF1 & TF3 are not. Is this a bug with adding multiple TextFields in SwiftUI or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997858/cant-find-keyplane-that-supports-type-4-for-keyboard-error-uitextfield-focus). It seems to have fixed the issue on simulator for me but I cant test it on a physical device since none of my devices are on iOS 13.

Comment: I tested on the real device and it works fine. On the simulator, the keyboard won't show initially, because it seems to default to software keyboard. By using CMD+K the keyboard shows up.

Comment: When  change the VStack to a Form the Textfields are able to be interacted with but that's not the design I am after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding answer to benefit others.

having played around with it the solution was to remove .cornerRadius and the all the TextFields work.

```
 VStack{
//TF1
    TextField("Duty", text: $dutyNumber)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .padding([.leading], 50)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)

      HStack{
//TF2
    TextField("Start time", text: $dutyStartTime)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .padding([.leading], 50)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
//TF3 
    TextField("Finish time", text: $dutyFinishTime)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            .padding([.leading], 50)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)

        }
    }//.cornerRadius(4)
```

Comment: But why it did fixed?

Comment: didn't work!! why Apple doesn't fix this stupid bug