# iOS 9/Swift 2 input from numpad can't find keyplane

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have some very basic code which reads the text from a textfield when the user presses a button, and updates the text on a label.  I have the type of the input field set to number pad.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet var userGuessTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel!
  @IBAction func guess(sender: AnyObject) {

    let randomNumber = String(arc4random_uniform(11))

    if randomNumber == userGuessTextField.text {
      resultLabel.text = "You're right"
    } else {
      resultLabel.text = "Wrong! It was a \(randomNumber)"
    }
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

When I trigger my action, xCode throws this error:

> Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard
>   iPhone-PortraitTruffle-NumberPad; using
>   675849259_PortraitTruffle_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

EDIT:

Turns out this is not an error at all, but a simple logging statement.  I must have accidentally set a breakpoint in my action, giving it the look and feel of a crash. Thank you, first responder.

Comment: So let me get this straight. You tap on the UITextField and type into it and the warning does not show up. But when you tap the UIButton that fires your `@IBAction` that you've listed here, that's when you get this warning about "Can't find keyplane"?

Answer (score 13):

Laugh uncontrollably and just keep going. It's not an error. It's just a bit of fluff dropped into the console. Ignore it.

Comment: Ugh.  The first time it happened, it triggered a breakpoint.  Or I mistakenly set one.  Appeared as though the program were crashing.

Thanks!

Comment: I also get this when I set any textfield as numpad. So it's safe to just ignore this warning?

Answer (score 2):

It can happened sometime when you update xocode testing on Simulator you can try this [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900682/1180206):

> iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an error.** It just says cannot find keyplane..

[image: Screenshot]

You can switch to simulator keyboard from `Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard` or simply press `cmd + shift + k`

[image: Screenshot 1]

You can even ignore this ;-)