# Textfield not taking text hardware connection also in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a textfield but when i type anything on it, it does not type anything and gives some error in console, the error is this,

```
 GuardsAutoZone[8602:561262] Can't find keyplane that supports type 5 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitTruffle-PhonePad; using 431568380_PortraitTruffle_iPhone-Complex-Pad_Default
2017-09-20 11:02:18.810211+0500 GuardsAutoZone[8602:561262] [Common] _BSMachError: port 7803; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
2017-09-20 11:02:18.811661+0500 GuardsAutoZone[8602:561262] [Common] _BSMachError: port 7803; (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable to deallocate send right"
2017-09-20 11:08:28.089989+0500 GuardsAutoZone[8602:590122] [MC] Invalidating cache
2017-09-20 11:08:29.627719+0500 GuardsAutoZone[8602:590122] [MC] Invalidating cache
2017-09-20 11:08:29.818169+0500 GuardsAutoZone[8602:590122] [MC] Invalidating cache
2017-09-20 11:08:30.411266+0500 GuardsAutoZone[8602:590537] [MC] Invalidating cache
2017-09-20 11:08:30.845221+0500 GuardsAutoZone[8602:590122] [MC] Invalidating cache
2017-09-20 11:08:31.056884+0500 GuardsAutoZone[8602:590537] [MC] Invalidating cache
2017-09-20 11:08:32.092079+0500 GuardsAutoZone[8602:590122] [MC] Invalidating cache
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871532/xcode-ios-8-keyboard-types-not-supported

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode iOS 8 Keyboard types not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871532/xcode-ios-8-keyboard-types-not-supported)

Comment: i have done according to the link u provided but its still not typing anything after connecting the hardware keyboard, is it any issue from info.plist? @iPeter

Answer (score 0):

Make sure iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard is not checked if you aren't using a hardware keyboard.

Comment: no i'm not using hardware keyboard, i'm using simulator keyboard. @arpita

Comment: your question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871532/xcode-ios-8-keyboard-types-not-supported. 
It may help you

Comment: previously, when i type in a textfield it type the words from both hardware keyboard and simulator keyboard. @arpita

Comment: then you should try with changing the device in simulator.

Comment: First i have uncheck the connect to hardware keyboard option it takes text but when i check the hardware keyboard connection it does not take any word. @arpita

Comment: i don't have device , i'm testing on simulator only. @arpita