# In SwiftUI how to focus soft keypad on Simulator and Preview (it works on hardware)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, ios-simulator

I have nothing but praise for Paul Hudson's excellent [Hacking With Swift tutorials](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui) but when I build and run [Tutorial 10](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/hiding-the-keyboard), the soft keypad only comes into focus on hardware (*an iPhone 12 running iOS 15.6.1*) but not on Simulator or Xcode Preview. The following message appears in the Console area.

> Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard
> iPhone-PortraitChoco-DecimalPad; using
> 27100_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

On the Simulator the **Done** button appears at the bottom of the screen but does not appear on the Preview. I found similar issues pre-dating SwiftUI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44905495/2348597) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25617062/2348597). The most likely cause of the problem is that I have recreated the code incorrectly.

I am running Xcode 13.4.1 on MacOS 12.5.

Does someone else have the same problem running my code ? if not, what version of Xcode have you used ?

```
import SwiftUI

// Tutorial 10

 struct ContentView: View {

     @State private var checkAmount = 0.0
     @State private var numberOfPeople = 2
     @State private var tipPercentage = 20
     @FocusState private var amountIsFocused: Bool
     
     let tipPercentages = [10, 15, 20, 25, 0]
     
     var totalPerPerson: Double {
         let peopleCount = Double(numberOfPeople + 2)
         let tipSelection = Double(tipPercentage)
         
         let tipValue = checkAmount / 100 * tipSelection
         let grandTotal = checkAmount + tipValue
         let amountPerPerson = grandTotal / peopleCount

         return amountPerPerson
     }

     var body: some View {
         NavigationView {
             Form {
                 Section {
                     TextField("Amount", value: $checkAmount, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "USD"))
                     
                         .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                         .focused($amountIsFocused)
                     
                     Picker("Number of people", selection: $numberOfPeople) {
                         ForEach(2 ..< 100) {
                             Text("\($0) people")
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 Section {
                     Picker("Tip percentage", selection: $tipPercentage) {
                         ForEach(tipPercentages, id: \.self) {
                             Text($0, format: .percent)
                         }
                     }
                     .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                 } header: {
                     Text("How much tip do you want to leave?")
                 }
                 Section {
                     Text(totalPerPerson, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "USD"))
                }
                 .navigationTitle("WeSplit")
                 .toolbar {
                     ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                         Button("Done") {
                             amountIsFocused = false
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to happen the following Simulator settings apply

```
Simulator, I/O, Keyboard, Connect Hardware Keyboard
```

When the app is built and run, Connect Hardware Keyboard is **checked** by default. In which case Command + k key will cause the software keyboard to be displayed. The app will operate on keystrokes either from the software keyboard or the qwerty keyboard. But if the user enters a value via the qwerty keyboard, this will immediately dismiss the software keyboard.

However, if Connect Hardware Keyboard is **unchecked**, the numeric keypad appears on the screen. The Qwerty keyboard is unresponsive and the on-screen numeric keypad offers the user only means of entering numeric values into the TextField via the Simulator.